# Passing Array from Activity to Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I know there a couple of threads similar to this one but they dont actually answer the above question. 
Firts question: is it true that only primitives can be passed? (String, boolean,...)
Second question: if it is so. I have an array of String in my activiy and i need it to fill a html table in my WebView and apparently i need to use Javascript interface to do so. So the question is: How can i do that? Do I need to create a string in my activity, pass it to JS and once there recreate the array?

Answer (score 2):

You could use JSON as format for your data. A simple way would be to use a lib like GSON http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ which makes it easy to convert your ArrayList with own object-types to Strings.

Send that to your WebView via the Javascript-interface and use JSON.parse(Stringname) in JS to recreate your Array.

Best wishes,
Tim

Comment: Danke Tim. I will give it a try. Someone also suggested me to try out JQuery. What do you think?

Comment: I really like jQuery on Android in WebViews (currently working on a project with that). It's fine to manipulate the DOM tree. Any questions?

Answer (score 1):

Your option is to expose the method using strings and then you can use the JSONObject or JSONArray to parse the string and use it accordingly.

Here is what I did.

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void passJSON(String array, String jsonObj) throws JSONException
{
    JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray(array);
    JSONObject myObj = new JSONObject(jsonObj);     
    ...

}
```

where array is '["string1","string2"]' and jsonObj is '{attr:1, attr2:"myName"}'

Answer (score 1):

"Do I need to create a string in my activity, pass it to JS and once there recreate the array?"
That's the way i resolved it in my case ; i appended a special character to each item in the list while building up the string and later split it up in JS.

```
var strings = get.list(); // long string from activity.
var item1 = strings.split("=")[0];
var item2 = strings.split("=")[1];
```

....
Or you could go for a library